# VBA Activepresentation.Saveas Error - 429 ActiveX

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to run the following code and when I get to the ActivePresentation.SaveAs i get the the following error

Error - Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.

I have googled around the issue and cant seem to find a clear answer, some threads suggest it could be a referencing issue however i have updated my references and the problem has persisted.

```
Public Sub SaveNewVersion_PowerPoint()
'PURPOSE: Save file, if already exists add a new version indicator to filename
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/The-Code-Vault

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim myPath As String
Dim SaveName As String
Dim SaveExt As String
Dim VersionExt As String
Dim Saved As Boolean
Dim x As Long
Dim TestStr As String
Dim myFileName As String


TestStr = ""
Saved = False
x = 2

'Version Indicator (change to liking)
  VersionExt = "_v"

'Pull info about file
  On Error GoTo NotSavedYet
    myPath = "C:\Users\Person\Desktop\Test\Weekly Pack Update.pptx"
    myFileName = Mid(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") + 1, InStrRev(myPath, ".") - InStrRev(myPath, "\") - 1)
    FolderPath = Left(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\"))
    SaveExt = "." & Right(myPath, Len(myPath) - InStrRev(myPath, "."))
  On Error GoTo 0

'Determine if file has ever been saved
  If FolderPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "This file has not been initially saved. " & _
    "Cannot save a new version!", vbCritical, "Not Saved To Computer"
    Exit Sub
  End If

'Determine Base File Name
  If InStr(1, myFileName, VersionExt) > 1 Then
    myArray = Split(myFileName, VersionExt)
    SaveName = myArray(0)
  Else
    SaveName = myFileName
  End If

'Test to see if file name already exists
  If FileExist(FolderPath & SaveName & SaveExt) = False Then
    ActivePresentation.SaveAs FolderPath & SaveName & SaveExt 'Errors Here
    Exit Sub
  End If

'Need a new version made
  Do While Saved = False
    If FileExist(FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt) = False Then
      ActivePresentation.SaveAs FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt 'Error Here
      Saved = True
    Else
      x = x + 1
    End If
  Loop

'New version saved
  MsgBox "New file version saved (version " & x & ")"

Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NotSavedYet:
  MsgBox "This file has not been initially saved. " & _
    "Cannot save a new version!", vbCritical, "Not Saved To Computer"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there actually a presentation open? Can you address it in the Immediate Window? Are you able to use SaveAs on it in the user interface? Are you sure all the variables have the expected values and concatenate to a viable file path?

Comment: The presentation is open, and its the only one open, i can save using the user UI, and I checked the variable and they do give a viable path, not sure exactly what you mean by immediate window though sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant claim to understand how this fixed it but i declared

```
Dim ppApp   As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres  As PowerPoint.Presentation
```

then added in

```
Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
i = 1

ppApp.Presentations.Open Filename:=myPath
Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Item(i)
```

finally changing

```
Activepresentation.saveAs
```

to

```
ppPres.SaveAs
```

and it worked
Full code below:

```
Public Sub SaveNewVersion_PowerPoint()
'PURPOSE: Save file, if already exists add a new version indicator to filename
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/The-Code-Vault

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim myPath As String
Dim SaveName As String
Dim SaveExt As String
Dim VersionExt As String
Dim Saved As Boolean
Dim x As Long
Dim TestStr As String
Dim myFileName As String


TestStr = ""
Saved = False
x = 2

'Version Indicator (change to liking)
  VersionExt = "_v"

'Pull info about file
  On Error GoTo NotSavedYet
    myPath = "C:\Users\Person\Desktop\Test\Weekly Pack Update.pptx"
    myFileName = Mid(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") + 1, InStrRev(myPath, ".") - InStrRev(myPath, "\") - 1)
    FolderPath = Left(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\"))
    SaveExt = "." & Right(myPath, Len(myPath) - InStrRev(myPath, "."))
  On Error GoTo 0

'Determine if file has ever been saved
  If FolderPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "This file has not been initially saved. " & _
    "Cannot save a new version!", vbCritical, "Not Saved To Computer"
    Exit Sub
  End If

'Determine Base File Name
  If InStr(1, myFileName, VersionExt) > 1 Then
    myArray = Split(myFileName, VersionExt)
    SaveName = myArray(0)
  Else
    SaveName = myFileName
  End If

'Test to see if file name already exists
  If FileExist(FolderPath & SaveName & SaveExt) = False Then
    ActivePresentation.SaveAs FolderPath & SaveName & SaveExt 'Errors Here
    Exit Sub
  End If

'Need a new version made
  Do While Saved = False
    If FileExist(FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt) = False Then
      ActivePresentation.SaveAs FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt 'Error Here
      Saved = True
    Else
      x = x + 1
    End If
  Loop

'New version saved
  MsgBox "New file version saved (version " & x & ")"

Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NotSavedYet:
  MsgBox "This file has not been initially saved. " & _
    "Cannot save a new version!", vbCritical, "Not Saved To Computer"

End Sub
```